# Python os.path.isdir() leaving out results

Tags: python, linux, directory, subdirectory, directory-structure

I'm trying to compare the sub-directories of two folders in Ubuntu by using Python 2.7.15's `os.listdir()` and `os.path.isdir()` in both directories, and I'm getting some odd results. Here is the directory structure:

```
super1
   sub1
   sub2
   sub3
super2
   sub1
   sub2
   sub4
```

Here is the code I have written (which is saved as `test.py` in the folder `super1`):

```
import os
import os.path
sourceFolders = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]
targetFolders = [g for g in os.listdir('../super2') if os.path.isdir(g)]
for name in sourceFolders:
   print(name)
for name in targetFolders:
   print(name)
```

The output:

```
sub1
sub2
sub3
sub1
sub2
```

Issue is that for whatever reason, it's skipping sub4 from super2. Using `os.path.isdir('../super2/sub4')` returns true, and if I just assign `targetFolders = os.listdir('../super2')` sub4 is included in the list. But if I then run

```
for name2 in targetFolders:
   if os.path.isdir(name2):
      print(name2)
```

it skips `sub4` again.
I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas?